# Plot max of graph using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to python and have a question. I've figured out how to graph functions, but how do I plot a point which indicates the max and minimum values? Here is my code, and it graphs properly I believe. Thank you.

```
    import numpy as np  
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    def graph(formula, x_range):  
        x = np.array(x_range)  
        y = eval(formula)
        plt.plot(x, y)  
        plt.show()

    graph('-x**4 + 508 * x + 40', range(-10, 200))
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you be plotting a single point?  Is the idea to superimpose it onto another plot?

Comment: Oh, I'm just trying to learn how to use python, don't really have a purpose yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n_max = y.argmax()
plt.plot(x[n_max],y[n_max],'o')
n_min = y.argmin()
plt.plot(x[n_min],y[n_min],'x')
```

something like this?